# Distribution fitting of Multiple columns

Tags: python, statistics, distribution, data-fitting, scipy.stats

I am trying to get the distribution fitting of my data using [scipy.stats](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html). The data contains multiple columns `col_1, col_2, col_3` in a single CSV file.

- The problem is distribution fitting only takes a single column to identify a best distribution fittings as  I have shown in the below code.
- How to get the distribution fitting of all columns at the same time? e.g distribution fitting of`col_1, col_2, col_3`

  ```
   import warnings
   warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np
   import scipy
   from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
   import scipy.stats
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

   # Load data and select first column

   from sklearn import datasets
   data_set = datasets.load_breast_cancer()

   # Multiple columns of csv
   col_1=data_set.data[:,0]
   col_2=data_set.data[:,1]
   col_3=data_set.data[:,2]

   # Create an index array (x) for data

   x = np.arange(len(col_1))
   size = len(col_1)

   plt.hist(col_1)
   plt.show()


   sc=StandardScaler() 
   yy = col_1.reshape (-1,1)
   sc.fit(yy)
   y_std =sc.transform(yy)
   y_std = y_std.flatten()
   y_std
   del yy


   dist_names = ['beta',
                 'expon',
                 'gamma',
                 'lognorm',
                 'norm',
                 'pearson3',
                 'triang',
                 'uniform',
                 'weibull_min', 
                 'weibull_max']

   # Set up empty lists to stroe results
   chi_square = []
   p_values = []


   # Set up 50 bins for chi-square test
   # Observed data will be approximately evenly distrubuted aross all bins
   percentile_bins = np.linspace(0,100,51)
   percentile_cutoffs = np.percentile(y_std, percentile_bins)
   observed_frequency, bins = (np.histogram(y_std, bins=percentile_cutoffs))
   cum_observed_frequency = np.cumsum(observed_frequency)



   # Loop through candidate distributions

   for distribution in dist_names:
       # Set up distribution and get fitted distribution parameters
       dist = getattr(scipy.stats, distribution)
       param = dist.fit(y_std)

       # Obtain the KS test P statistic, round it to 5 decimal places
       p = scipy.stats.kstest(y_std, distribution, args=param)[1]
       p = np.around(p, 5)
       p_values.append(p)    

       # Get expected counts in percentile bins
       # This is based on a 'cumulative distrubution function' (cdf)
       cdf_fitted = dist.cdf(percentile_cutoffs, *param[:-2], loc=param[-2], 
                             scale=param[-1])
       expected_frequency = []
       for bin in range(len(percentile_bins)-1):
           expected_cdf_area = cdf_fitted[bin+1] - cdf_fitted[bin]
           expected_frequency.append(expected_cdf_area)

       # calculate chi-squared
       expected_frequency = np.array(expected_frequency) * size
       cum_expected_frequency = np.cumsum(expected_frequency)
       ss = sum (((cum_expected_frequency - cum_observed_frequency) ** 2) / cum_observed_frequency)
       chi_square.append(ss)

   # Collate results and sort by goodness of fit (best at top)

   results = pd.DataFrame()
   results['Distribution'] = dist_names
   results['chi_square'] = chi_square
   results['p_value'] = p_values
   results.sort_values(['chi_square'], inplace=True)

   # Report results

   print ('\nDistributions sorted by goodness of fit:')
   print ('----------------------------------------')
   print (results)
  ```

Comment: Why not concatenate the columns into a single list?

Comment: Every column data have different distribution fitting and characteristics. Merging into one will not make a clear sense of each column distribution.

Comment: What do you mean by "at the same time". If they are independent then successive fitting would just be fine. Do they join a parameter? Then it becomes more tricky.